# Unpublish app from Play store and inform existing users

Tags: android, google-play

I wish to unpublish an app from Play Store and inform all existing users to move to a new app location at Play store. I understand that once I unpublish an app, new users will not be able to view it, but existing users are still tied up to it. Is there a way to inform existing users to move to the new app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the existing app to include the disclaimer, and that "Support for App XYZ will be discontinued beginning `<Date>`, at which point you might consider using App ABC `<link to play store>`".

Then unpublish the app on that Date. Users who installed XYZ previously will still get the latest published version (via auto-update or when they see it has an update in their installed apps list), while others who haven't downloaded it at all before will have no idea that app XYZ existed at all.