# Problems with "Google Play App Signing"

Tags: android, google-play

When I first published my app on google play,  I did not interact and enabled "Google Play App Signing".

Now I'm dealing with a serious problem and want to disable it, which unfortunately is not possible.

When I wanted to remove my app from Google Play and publish it again without "Google Play App Signing", I realized that Google would not allow the removal of the published program.

How can I solve this problem and publish my app with my signature?

Please help me

---

My problem is with Google signing
I want to disable it

---

Comment: FYI you can _unpublish_ the apps from Google Play Store

Comment: How can I solve this problem and publish my app with my signature???, I want to delete Google signing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpublish app from Play store and inform existing users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900448/unpublish-app-from-play-store-and-inform-existing-users)

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for..
Thanks

Comment: @SVDev VERY Curious what your "serious issue" was/is with Google App Signing.

Answer (score 0):

Unpublish first and then remove.

Comment: Once you published your app or a particular version of it, you cannot delete it from the Market.

Comment: Where is the delete button? May you tell me?

Comment: As you said once you have published the application you can't delete it. However, you can delete draft apps.